# Typescript: Clicking 'X' doesn't successfully close my popup banner

Tags: css, reactjs, typescript, popup

I've created a popup banner with the following code (sorry if the format is off)

```
 //this is in folder Banner.tsx

  import React, {useCallback} from "react";
  type Properties = {
        close: () => void;
       text: string;

   const Banner: React.FC<Properties> = ({close, text}) => {
   const onClick = useCallback(() => {
                   close();},
                   [close, text]);
   return (
      <div className = "BannerBox">
           <div className = "banner">
          <span className = "popup"> {onClick}{close}[x]
          </span>
          {text}
          </div>
     </div>
     );
     };
   export default Banner;


//this is App.tsx

import Banner from "./Components/Banner";
function App(): JSX.Element {

const [isOpen, setIsOpen]=useState(false);
      const toggleBanner = () => {
      SetIsOpen(!isOpen);
};

return (
    <div>
      <input type = "button"
          value = "popup"
          onClick={toggleBanner}/>
          <p>hi</p>
          {isOpen && <Banner text = {"hello"} close={function (): void { throw new Error("Function not implemented.");
          } }/>}
    </div>
export default App;


 //this is my Banner.css file (let me know if you need the full code but this is some of it)

.BannerBox{
 position: fixed;
 background: blue;
 width:50%;

 }
 
 .banner{
 position: relative;
 width: 100%;
 }

 .popup{
 content: 'x';
 position: fixed;
 background: green;
 
 }
```

the code compiles just fine, I'm not getting any errors but the problem is that when the banner pop-ups, I can't close it by clicking 'X' i have to refresh the page in order to close the banner and I'm not sure how to fix that. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume that `close()` will actually close the popup banner since you did't show the implementation of it.

This line causes the issue

```
<span className = "popup">{onClick}{close}[x]</span>
```

You are supposed to pass a function to the `onClick` listener. Something like:

```
<span className = "popup" onClick={close}>[x]</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `close` function needs to be passed to the onClick callback for the span which is acting as the button. These are added as "attributes" for the jsx element. See below `onClick={onClick}` where your onClick callback function is passed by reference (notice no invoking parentheses within the curly braces)

In the return of Banner.tsx

```js
        <span className="popup" onClick={onClick}>
          [x]
        </span>
```

close is passed into your Banner component, so this needs to be implemented in your App component. I ensured it always closes by explicitly setting isOpen to false (instead of calling toggle)

in the return of App.tsx

```js
{isOpen && <Banner text={"hello"} close={() => setIsOpen(false)} />}
```

so in total

Banner.tsx

```js
import React, { useCallback } from "react";
import "./Banner.css";

type Properties = {
  close: () => void;
  text: string;
};

const Banner: React.FC<Properties> = ({ close, text }) => {
  const onClick = useCallback(() => {
    close();
  }, [close]);

  return (
    <div className="BannerBox">
      <div className="banner">
        <span className="popup" onClick={onClick}>
          [x]
        </span>
        {text}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Banner;
```

and App.tsx

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";

import Banner from "./Components/Banner";

function App(): JSX.Element {
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleBanner = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="popup" onClick={toggleBanner} />
      <p>hi</p>
      {isOpen && <Banner text={"hello"} close={() => setIsOpen(false)} />}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

See codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-haze-617qi?file=/src/App.tsx:0-442)